# Cant edit hero widget to how i want

Tags: wordpress

i've been trying to fix this for an hour now (Im a beginner) and everything i'm doing hasn't changed it a single time.
My current site is this https://www.traveltradewinds.com/ttw/

On the home page, with the search your room section, im trying to make it look like this https://www.hotwire.com/hotels/

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i'm clueless on how to fix this, thank you

Comment: You can achieve it by css.

Comment: i tried adding css into it to change it but it had no effect, i dont even know how to begin changing the css for it either, im just looking for some help getting started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code. try this.
But, I don't know How to send the all css code with class name.

[image]

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em)
.hero .hero-inner {
width: 100% !important;
float: left;
margin-left: 1.38889%;
margin-right: 1.38889%;
}


.hero .hero-inner {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin-left: 1.38889%;
margin-right: 1.38889%;
}



ul{
 display:flex;
 }
```

Put this css code in your form Tag

```
form{
border: 1px solid white;
background: white;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.widget ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


.hero .widget ul li, .hero .widget ol li {
list-style: none;
height: 48px;
margin: 50px 15px;
height: 48px;
margin: 50px 15px;
}

.hb-submit{
 text-align:center;
 }
```

And i removed the Arrival Date, Departure Date, Adults, and Children labels from your code.

Try These code.

Comment: @Adam Steele  I have Updated my code. See above code. If you have any issue, put !important to each line of this code.

Comment: Hello, i am using wordpress so i'm unsure on how to add the code, i tried adding this exact code into the styles.css and it didn't seem to work? Am i placing it in the wrong place?

Comment: @AdamSteele Did you add it in the end? Can you try Custom CSS in the theme or through a plugin?

Comment: @ManojKumar hello, yes i tried adding it through the Custom CSS feature, and this is what happened (https://gyazo.com/865e21844c78eaf247f2241a759727b9)

Comment: The answer is missing a class for the first four properties of 2nd snippet. Notice the error icon on the left in the screenshot.

Comment: Now try my updated code. You have to mention some class name in your code

Comment: Okay, that code majority fixed it, it now looks like this, with this error on line 2 (https://gyazo.com/61495f313ba02a6e7524750ef67e0351), so i tried to fix it and it ends up like this (https://gyazo.com/cb755f3b293fefecd23421047070a54b) i added { at the end of line 1 and closed it at line 7

Comment: Ohh, sorry its my mistake. I forgot to update some lines. Now check it with my updated code

Comment: the error code associated with "ul" says its expecting a colon (https://gyazo.com/479f5b2b6ba5696bc113cc2ad52ad46e)

Comment: @Adam Steele  Again I am sorry, It's     display: flex;

Comment: @A.Sakkeer perfect! thank you so much for the help, its working brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried form-inline with **Bootstrap Inline Form** . please try it with form-group in form-inline

Comment: how do i do this in wordpress?